# JavaScript: implement sequential keyboard hotkey?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

For example, I want to implement something like do action when you typed sequentially `shift-s` then `s`, in JavaScript. I'm inspired by Autohokey, hotkey configuration software/language for Windows, so I'm looking for a library or way to implement something that in JS.

So far I found a library called [hotkeys](https://github.com/jaywcjlove/hotkeys), but I have no idea to implement a sequential keyboard hotkey and didn't find any issue or question about it also, so here I am. So, how can I implement that in JS using the library or other library? Thanks.

Comment: FYI A sequence of keyboard shortcuts or hotkeys are commonly called chords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easy with keydown event listener, no library needed for this

```js
sAgain = false

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (sAgain && event.key.toLowerCase() == 's')
    alert("shift-s then s clicked")
  else if (event.shiftKey && event.key.toLowerCase() == 's')
    sAgain = true
  else
    sAgain = false //stop listen if other key is clicked after shift-s
});
```

```html
<h1>Press shift s then s<h1>
```